# Clarification in deploying a Django App on amazon ec2 server

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to learn how to deploy an app with Django using Amazon ec2 server

I am following this tutorial for Django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I follow the following step in the server set up

```
~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
~$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
~$ sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
~$ sudo pip install Django
~$ sudo python setup.py install

~$ sudo apt-get install subversion

~$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

<location>
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
    PythonOption django.root
    PythonDebug On
    PythonPath "['/home/shabda/testproject', '/var'] + sys.path"
</location>

Alias /media /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
<location media="">
    SetHandler None
</location>

Alias /static /var/www_django/static
<location static="">
    SetHandler None
</location>
```

Now if I connect to my web page

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eerqtcr7pig4zls/Screenshot%202014-04-24%2018.00.25.png

However if I launch it at local host

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This show up

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e67agpb7g6i3b7n/Screenshot%202014-04-24%2018.00.45.png

So there is a discrepancy between the server content, and the localhost content, I am trying to make the server content the same as what is showed on localhost

I am guessing I am missing some steps, can anyone give me some hint

Thanks

Comment: [Here's](http://markhops.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-setting-up-ec2-and-django.html) a good tutorial. Maybe work through that and see if you can fix it?

Comment: I tried the tutorial, but my front page is still the ubuntu one, although, one thing I am quite confuse is that the ubuntu page ask me to replace `(located at /var/www/html/index.html) ` however what do I replace with?

Comment: You need to replace the contents of the /var/www/ directory. See step 11 (adding /apache/django.wsgi). Make sure you've also you have /var/www/apache/django.wsgi referenced in the httpd conf (step 10). Also, are you directing to the correct url?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I finish all the steps up to 15 but I don't see that I replaced the index.html, as the index.html is still the original one, also what is the correct url, I am using the public dns that ec2 gived me, is that not the correct url? `http://ec2-somenumber.compute.amazonaws.com/` maybe I should remove the html folder?